# Tell gcc that a function call will not return

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning, noreturn

I am using `C99` under `GCC`.

I have a function declared `static` `inline` in a header that I cannot modify.

The function never returns but is not marked `__attribute__((noreturn))`.

How can I call the function in a way that tells the compiler it will not return?

I am calling it from my own noreturn function, and partly want to suppress the "noreturn function returns" warning but also want to help the optimizer etc.

I have tried including a declaration with the attribute but get a warning about the repeated declaration.

I have tried creating a function pointer and applying the attribute to that, but it says the function attribute cannot apply to a pointed function.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to ignore a function output? Just because a function returns a value doesn't mean that any function which calls that function has to return the value too? Any code samples?

Comment: Can you show how your noreturn function is defined?

Comment: This is great to get rid of non-relevant warnings on functions that exit or throw exceptions. You do not need kind of return something.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From the function *you* defined, and which calls the external function, add a call to `__builtin_unreachable` which is built into at least [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) and [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) compilers and is marked `noreturn`. In fact, this function does nothing else and should not be called. It's only here so that the compiler can infer that program execution will stop at this point.

```
static inline external_function() // lacks the noreturn attribute
{ /* does not return */ }

__attribute__((noreturn)) void your_function() {
    external_function();     // the compiler thinks execution may continue ...
    __builtin_unreachable(); // ... and now it knows it won't go beyond here
}
```

**Edit:** Just to clarify a few points raised in the comments, and generally give a bit of context:

- A function has has only two ways of not returning: loop forever, or short-circuit the usual control-flow (e.g. throw an exception, jump out of the function, terminate the process, etc.)
- In some cases, the compiler *may* be able to infer and prove through static analysis that a function will not return. Even theoretically, this is [not always possible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), and since we want compilers to be *fast* only obvious/easy cases are detected.
- `__attribute__((noreturn))` is an annotation (like `const`) which is a way for the programmer to inform the compiler that he's absolutely sure a function will not return. Following the *trust but verify* principle, the compiler tries to prove that the function does indeed not return. If may then issue an error if it proves the function may return, or a warning if it was not able to prove whether the function returns or not.
- `__builtin_unreachable` has *undefined behaviour* because it is not meant to be called. It's only meant to help the compiler's static analysis. Indeed the compiler knows that this function does not return, so any following code is provably unreachable (except through a jump).

Once the compiler has established (either by itself, or with the programmer's help) that some code is unreachable, it may use this information to do optimizations like these:

- Remove the boilerplate code used to return from a function to its caller, if the function never returns
- Propagate the *unreachability* information, i.e. if the only execution path to a code points is through unreachable code, then this point is also unreachable. Examples:

  - if a function does not return, any code *following* its call and not reachable through jumps is also unreachable. Example: code following `__builtin_unreachable()` is unreachable.
  - in particular, it the only path to a function's return is through unreachable code, the function can be marked `noreturn`. That's what happens for `your_function`.
  - any memory location / variable only used in unreachable code is not needed, therefore settings/computing the content of such data is not needed.
  - any computations which is probably **(1)** unnecessary (previous bullet) and **(2)** has no side effects (such as `pure` functions) may be removed.

Illustration:

- The call to `external_function` cannot be removed because it might have side-effects. In fact, it probably has at least the side effect of terminating the process!
- The return boiler plate of `your_function` may be removed

Here's another example showing how code **before** the unreachable point may be removed

```
int compute(int) __attribute((pure)) { return /* expensive compute */ }
if(condition) {
    int x = compute(input); // (1) no side effect => keep if x is used
                            // (8) x is not used  => remove
    printf("hello ");       // (2) reachable + side effect => keep
    your_function();        // (3) reachable + side effect => keep
                            // (4) unreachable beyond this point
    printf("word!\n");      // (5) unreachable => remove
    printf("%d\n", x);      // (6) unreachable => remove
                            // (7) mark 'x' as unused
} else {
                            // follows unreachable code, but can jump here
                            // from reachable code, so this is reachable
   do_stuff();              // keep
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a difference between `__builtin_unreachable()` and *not returning*? In particular, `__builtin_unreachable` tells the compiler that the location is unreachable -- so it might assume that anything not coming out of a jump from above it is also unreachable. In your example, the call to `external_function()` is not conditional. Therefore it could be assumed that it also is unreachable?

Comment: @intekngt: you are probably wrong. Read [more about `__builtin_unreachable`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins) ...

Comment: @inetknght: From a behaviour point of view there are only two ways of not retruning: loop forever or abort execution. `builtin_unreachable` does one of those things (I think which one is undefined) *and tells it to the compiler* in case it's not smart enough to find out from static analysis. In any case, when the compiler finds an unreachable location, it can optimize code before it, like you said, **only if it can prove that code has no side effect**, like a *pure* function. In our case, `external_function` is not pure and could write a file or such, and cannot be optimized out.

Comment: I edited to explain in a bit more depth how compilers can take advantage of unreachable code, hope it makes sense :)

Comment: There is a 3rd way of not returning: exceptions (or longjmp). At least leaving a function via an uncaught exception is not considered returning by gcc's attribute. That doesn't affect the answer though.

Comment: indeed, I realized that after posting ;) Also things like coroutines or anything low level playing with the stack and/or jumping out of the function

Comment: Given `extern volatile int STOP_CPU_AND_KILL_POWER_WHEN_READ; void shutdown(void) {+STOP_CPU_AND_KILL_POWER_WHEN_READ; __dmb(); __builtin_unreachable();`} would the `__builtin_unreachable()` cause the compiler to infer that `shutdown` could not be called, or merely that it didn't have to generate a return instruction?  Would there be any way to avoid having the compiler generate a needless return instruction without causing it to generate any other needless code?

Comment: @supercat: because of `volatile` access to your `int` won't be optimized away and the `shutdown()` will be called. The compiler **may** remove the return code (it probably will in practice), but I don't know a way to *force* it (aport from assembler). If you mark the function `inline` or stronger compiler-specific attributes like `always_inline` or `__forceinline`, it can also remove the call overhead.

Comment: @Antoine: Is there anything in the Standard that would forbid a compiler from moving UB before a volatile read?  If the code were written as `while (STOP_CPU_AND_KILL_POWER_WHEN_READ) {} __builtin_unreachable();` a compiler would clearly be required to allow for the possibility that the indicated location might never return zero, but that would require the compiler to generate a useless conditional branch.  Otherwise, the most useful semantics would probably be to have two kinds of `volatile` qualifiers--one of which only sequenced accesses relative to other `volatile` access, and one which...

Comment: ...also sequenced it relative to anything that might cause Undefined Behavior, but I know of no hint of such a feature in any C implementation.  There are many cases where e.g. moving a division operation before a volatile access could be a useful optimization (especially if it can be hoisted out of a loop), and very few volatile accesses would prevent subsequent code execution, so I know of nothing in the Standard which would require compilers to use the latter semantics.  Personally I think the right approach from a language-design standpoint would be to say that normative implementations...

Comment: ...must include whatever checks would be required to prevent any trap behavior from moving forward (generally not expensive--on every CPU I've ever heard of the cost of dividing unknown values dwarfs the cost of an error-preventing check), and allow implementations to specify that they are compliant but non-normative, but I'm not sure such a thing could ever fly politically.

Answer (score 8):

Several solutions:

#### redeclaring your function with the `__attribute__`

You should try to modify that function in its header by adding `__attribute__((noreturn))` to it.

You can redeclare some functions with new attribute, as this stupid test demonstrates (adding an attribute to `fopen`) :

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 extern FILE *fopen (const char *__restrict __filename,
            const char *__restrict __modes)
   __attribute__ ((warning ("fopen is used")));

 void
 show_map_without_care (void)
 {
   FILE *f = fopen ("/proc/self/maps", "r");
   do
     {
       char lin[64];
       fgets (lin, sizeof (lin), f);
       fputs (lin, stdout);
     }
   while (!feof (f));
   fclose (f);
 }
```

---

#### overriding with a macro

At last, you could define a macro like

```
#define func(A) {func(A); __builtin_unreachable();}
```

(this uses the fact that inside a macro, the macro name is not macro-expanded).

If your never-returning `func` is declaring as returning e.g. `int` you'll use a [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) like

```
#define func(A) ({func(A); __builtin_unreachable(); (int)0; })
```

Macro-based solutions like above won't always work, e.g. if `func` is passed as a function pointer, or simply if some guy codes `(func)(1)` which is legal but ugly.

---

#### redeclaring a static inline with the `noreturn`  attribute

And the following example:

```
 // file ex.c
 // declare exit without any standard header
 void exit (int);

 // define myexit as a static inline
 static inline void
 myexit (int c)
 {
   exit (c);
 }

 // redeclare it as notreturn
 static inline void myexit (int c) __attribute__ ((noreturn));

 int
 foo (int *p)
 {
   if (!p)
     myexit (1);
   if (p)
     return *p + 2;
   return 0;
 }
```

when compiled with GCC 4.9 (from Debian/Sid/x86-64) as `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O2 ex.c`) gives an assembly file containing the expected optimization:

```
         .type   foo, @function
 foo:
 .LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    testq   %rdi, %rdi      # p
    je      .L5     #,
    movl    (%rdi), %eax    # *p_2(D), *p_2(D)
    addl    $2, %eax        #, D.1768
    ret
.L5:
    pushq   %rax    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movb    $1, %dil        #,
    call    exit    #
    .cfi_endproc
 .LFE1:
    .size   foo, .-foo
```

You could play with [#pragma GCC diagnostic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) to selectively disable a warning.

---

#### Customizing [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with [MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/)

Finally, you could customize your recent `gcc` using the [MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) plugin and coding your simple extension (in the *MELT* domain specific language) to add the attribute `noreturn` when encoutering the desired function. It is probably a dozen of MELT lines, using `register_finish_decl_first` and a match on the function name.

<sup>Since I am the main author of *MELT* (free software GPLv3+) I could perhaps even code that for you if you ask, e.g. here or preferably on `gcc-melt@googlegroups.com`; give the concrete name of your never-returning function.</sup>

Probably the MELT code is looking like:

```
  ;;file your_melt_mode.melt
  (module_is_gpl_compatible "GPLv3+")
  (defun my_finish_decl (decl)
     (let ( (tdecl (unbox :tree decl))
       )
     (match tdecl
        (?(tree_function_decl_named
            ?(tree_identifier ?(cstring_same "your_function_name")))
          ;;; code to add the noreturn attribute
          ;;; ....
        ))))
  (register_finish_decl_first my_finish_decl)
```

<sup>The real MELT code is slightly more complex. You want to define `your_adding_attr_mode` there. Ask me for more.</sup>

Once you coded your MELT extension `your_melt_mode.melt`  for your needs (and compiled that MELT extension into `your_melt_mode.quicklybuilt.so` as [documented](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/docum.html) in the MELT tutorials) you'll compile your code with

```
  gcc -fplugin=melt \
      -fplugin-arg-melt-extra=your_melt_mode.quicklybuilt \
      -fplugin-arg-melt-mode=your_adding_attr_mode \
      -O2 -I/your/include -c yourfile.c
```

In other words, you just add a few `-fplugin-*` flags to your `CFLAGS` in your `Makefile` !

BTW, I'm just coding in the MELT monitor (on github: https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor ..., file `meltmom-process.melt` something quite similar.

With a MELT extension, you won't get any additional warning, since the MELT extension would alter the internal GCC AST (a GCC *Tree*) of the declared function on the fly!

Customizing GCC with MELT is probably the most bullet-proof solution, since it is modifying the GCC internal AST. Of course, it is probably the most costly solution (and it is GCC specific and might need -small- changes when GCC is evolving, e.g. when using the next version of GCC), but as I am trying to show it is quite easy in your case.

PS. In 2019, GCC MELT is an abandoned project. If you want to customize GCC (for any recent version of GCC, e.g. GCC 7, 8, or 9), you need to write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) in C++.

Comment: Thanks Basile for the three solutions,

1) As I mentioned in the question, I cannot modify the header.

2) I think the macro solution is ugly, but I could just add __builtin_unreachable() directly after the call site; I am able to modify the calling code.

As I also mentioned in the question, redeclaring the function with the attribute generates a "redundant redeclaration" warning.  Is there a way of adding the attribute without triggering this warning?

Comment: Surely with a MELT extension you won't have any warnings, since the declaration of `your_function_name` will be modified *on the fly* when GCC is parsing your sacred and untouchable header....