# Is there an attribute to tell the compiler to ignore a missing return statement?

Tags: c

I don't believe this is a duplicate because the function *does* return in the happy path. Using the attribute `no-return` allows the compiler to optimise on the assumption that the function never returns, which is not the case here.

I have come C code that either returns a pointer or calls another function to exit out of the program. This is in an `if` statement, so either it returns the result or exits. As the function returns a `void *`, the compiler warns that it's possible the function won't return a value (which is of course true):

`error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]`

I can get around this by just adding `return *temp;` to the end of the function but I'd like to be clear in my intent by having something like the unused variable attribute:

`__attribute__((__unused__))`

That way I can leave `-Wall` on and not have to add unnecessary or possibly confusing code.

I'd also be up for rewriting the code if there's a better way to express this intent.

The code looks something like:

```
void *get_memory() {
    void *temp = malloc(100);
    if (temp) {
        // do some setup work
        return temp;
    } else {
        exit_program_with_epic_fail();
    }
    // Compiler warns if the following line isn't present
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code *around* the actual return and the call that goes to exit?

Comment: The problem is rather the function that *exits* - [it is the one that should be annotated with `noreturn`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408795/tell-gcc-that-a-function-call-will-not-return)!

Comment: How about: `if (!temp) {` `exit_program_with_epic_fail();` `}` `/* do some setup work */` `return temp;`? Or: `if (temp) {` `/* do some setup work */` `} else {` `exit_program_with_epic_fail();` `}` `return temp;`?

Comment: @IanAbbott  That is such an obvious answer - guess I didn't see the wood for the trees!  I'd be keen to see if there is a compiler attribute for this use case, but if not, if you put that as the answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to get rid of the warning:

- tag the `exit_program_with_epic_fail()` function with the appropriate attribute, `_Noreturn` in C11, but there is no portable way to do this to pre-C11 compilers. Many compilers support `__attribute__((noreturn))`, notably **gcc**, **clang** and **tinycc**, but it is an compiler specific extension.
- reorganise the code to let the compiler see the function always return.

Here is a modified version:

```
void *get_memory(void) {
    void *temp = malloc(100);
    if (!temp) {
        exit_program_with_epic_fail();
    }
    // do some setup work
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a pure design problem.

The warning/error "control reaches end of non-void function" isn't the problem, it is rather just an indicator telling you where the actual problem is.

You could/should simply rewrite the function as

```
void *get_memory (void) 
{
  void *temp = malloc(100);
  if(temp != NULL)
  {
    // do stuff
  }

  return temp;
}
```

And leave error handling to the caller. Because it is not an allocation function's job to terminate the application - that's bad design.

Alternative version with detailed error handling:

```
typedef enum
{
  OK,
  ERR_OUTOFMEMORY,
  ...
} err_t;

err_t get_memory (void** mem) 
{
  *mem = malloc(100);
  if(*mem == NULL)
  {
    return ERR_OUTOFMEMORY;
  }

  // do stuff

  return OK;
}
```

Comment: *"it is not an allocation function's job to terminate the application"* That's debatable.  When `malloc` and family start failing that typically means the system is out of memory, so for most apps there's not much to do other than `exit`.  It also centralizes the error handling.

Comment: @dbush It's always best to centralize error handling at the top level. If the program can't continue executing even the clean-up because there's no memory, then it probably won't matter how you write it. But if it can, it is convenient to know where the program failed and why. That is, it failed at the 666th call to `get_memory`, not just "it failed to allocate memory".

Comment: @Lundin In this case though, the allocation function (it isn't `malloc` in the actual code), would require custom handling in many different places - all of which would simply terminate the program. At least for my use case, knowing what failed to allocated the memory or which attempt failed isn't useful - it can't get memory and it can't continue, so log and exit quickly so the system can restart it. I'm certainly interested in knowing better ways to handle this particular issue! :)

Comment: @PeterM The call to terminate the program should come from the main application, not by a module/library used by it, period. And the main application is where you should centralize error handling too, at the top layer. Nothing reeks more than de-centralized error handling.

Comment: @PeterM One typical example of crappy libraries are those who localized error handling of things that "will never happen anyway". Often "unexpected errors" don't happen because of that theoretical, unexpected thing which will never happen, but because of plain old bugs. It is for example far more likely that your pointer to malloc'd memory gets set to null because of buffer overruns or runaway code, than the computer having no memory left.

Comment: @Lundin This is not an external library, nor is there any localized error handling. The app has a single function for doing a fast exit simply because given its use case, it is preferable to simply bail and restart the app than it is to try and fix many problems. This greatly simplifies the program design and removes a lot of boilerplate error handling code. Whilst it is true that a null pointer could be caused by an overrun or runaway code, this would also put the app into an undefined state that would not be possible to safely recover from - hence die fast and allow safe recovery.